# Find files selected by the config spec with specific properties in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I am using Clearcase dynamic view with a complex config spec. I need a command line command to find files where the version selected by the config spec has a specific property, such as:

- has a specific label
- does not have a specific label
- is on a specific branch
- etc.

I was looking at the documentation of the `cleartool find` command, but found no rule such as "version selected by the config spec".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple

```
cleartool describe -l /path/to/your/view/path/to/your/file
```

should be enough to display all the informations you need.

Combine that with the [`fmt_ccase` formatting options page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), and you can display directly only the label and the branch name:

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%Sn %l" /path/to/your/view/path/to/your/file
```

See:

```
%Sn
```

> Short name:
>   For a version, a short form of the version ID: `branch-pathname/version-number`.
>   For other objects, the null string.

---

Now, if you want to find all files with a version of a specific property *within* your view, use the `-cview` option of `find`.
See "[Additional examples of the `cleartool find` command](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)":

> To print all versions selected by your view that have a LABEL applied:

```
cleartool find . -cview -version "lbtype(LABEL)" -print
```

Following the same idea:

To print all versions selected by your view that are in a given branch:

```
cleartool find . -cview -version "brtype(BRNAME)" -print
```